# Is there an alternative to dotnet blazor asp.net hosted in Rider

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, rider, jetbrains-rider

In visual studio I can select a webassembly app with the option asp.net core hosted.
This creates a wasm client app and the corresponding server part and also a shared space.
Currently I am evaluating JetBrain's Rider as IDE. Great tool but I am kind of lost with this project type. In Rider I got only "Blazor Web App" or "Blazor Webassembly Standalone App"
There is no such option as "ASP.NET hosted". Which of those project types is the current alternative? Maybe I am missing something here. My goal is to have a wasm blazor app where I can separate all API calls into the server part. So that my API keys and so on are hidden within the server part.
What am I missing?

Have been trying the available project types on Rider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Rider so you may get an better answer that this.

I think you're confusing Net7.0 and Net8.0 templates.

The *Web Assembly* template with the *ASP.NET hosted* option is a Net7.0 template.

*Blazor Web App* and *Blazor Webassembly Standalone App* are Net8.0 templates.  All *Blazor Web App* template solutions are *ASP.NET hosted*. The *Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App* is not hosted.

Select *Blazor Web App* with Interactive render mode set to *WebAssembly* and Interactivity location set to *Global* for the Net8.0 equivalent of *Web Assembly* template with the *ASP.NET hosted*.  There are now only two projects: there's no *Shared*.

What version of Net do you want to use?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You are absolutely right, I was confused by the template changes. When I select the "old" .net7 sdk the hosted option appears again. With .net 8 it is as described by you, except you can't set interactive render mode, and interactivity location. At least not within the project wizard.